# Using CSS nth-child, how to iterate over X elements in groups of Y?

Tags: html, css

We have a series of items that are laid out in a rows in two-column `display: grid`.

We also have 5 branded colors: orange, blue, yellow, green, pink.

The background colors of the rows should iterate over those colors in order, e.g.:

- Row 1: orange
- Row 2: blue
- Row 3: yellow
- Row 4: green
- Row 5: pink
- Row 6: (back to the first of the 5 colors) orange
- Row 7: blue
- ...etc.

I know how to iterate over every *one* item using `:nth-child(5n + 1)`, as shown in the snippet below. This works fine if we have a `<table>` where each pair of items is enclosed in a `<tr>`.

But in this case the items are not grouped, and we want to iterate over every *two* items. How do we accomplish the effect of coloring by row?

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

li:nth-child(5n + 1) {
  background: orange;
}

li:nth-child(5n + 2) {
  background: blue;
}

li:nth-child(5n + 3) {
  background: yellow;
}

li:nth-child(5n + 4) {
  background: green;
}

li:nth-child(5n + 5) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
<ul>
```

Comment: you consider `10n + x` and you color two consecutive items with the same color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to use `10n` instead of `5n`, so the first two elements will be `li:nth-child(10n + 1), li:nth-child(10n + 2)`

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

li:nth-child(10n + 1),
li:nth-child(10n + 2) {
  background: orange;
}

li:nth-child(10n + 3),
li:nth-child(10n + 4) {
  background: blue;
}

li:nth-child(10n + 5),
li:nth-child(10n + 6) {
  background: yellow;
}

li:nth-child(10n + 7),
li:nth-child(10n + 8) {
  background: green;
}

li:nth-child(10n + 9),
li:nth-child(10n) {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <ul>
```

Comment: D'oh! I was trying to do it with one selector per row, and didn't even consider using two selectors per row. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are using a fixed height for rows, so consider a gradient:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(
     orange 0 50px,
     blue   0 100px,
     yellow 0 150px,
     green  0 200px,
     pink   0 250px
    );
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```